# mysql select replaces double quote with hashtag

Tags: mysql

I have been reading through documentation and scouring the google-net trying to figure out how to construct a select query for mysql that returns double quotes that are in varchar fields.

Everything I find says not to insert quotes in the first place without escaping them.  Agreed 100%... but I have received the database from someone else.  They created it using MySQL Workbench... which allows them to enter double quote values in a varchar field.   How the heck do I get the double quote back out?  Both mysql client (command line) and mysqli (php) convert the double quote to a hash tag.

I could dump the database, go through it manually replacing all quotes, and then reimport.  But this is only good until the next delivery I receive of this database.

What am I missing here?

(I tried adding screen shots, but Imagur doesn't seem to want to process them right now)... so here is copy/paste of what I'm seeing:

In MySQL Workbench (just the "value" field):

```
If you would like to keep your responses anonymous, you may do so.  Simply click on the ”anonymous” checkbox above each ”Feedback” block.   When you submit your survey, you will be sent a link, by email, to revisit/modify your responses. Hold onto that email as that will be the only mechanism for associating you with your anonymous responses.
```

From mysql client:

```
mysql> select * from survey_labels where item_id=149;
+---------+------+-------+--------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| item_id | type | level | italic | bold | size | value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+---------+------+-------+--------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     149 | text |     2 |      0 |    0 | NULL | If you would like to keep your responses anonymous, you may do so.  Simply click on the #anonymous# checkbox above each #Feedback# block.   When you submit your survey, you will be sent a link, by email, to revisit/modify your responses. Hold onto that email as that will be the only mechanism for associating you with your anonymous responses. |
+---------+------+-------+--------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.09 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [PHPs function htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to convert those special chars into [html-codes](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

But to your problem: Figure out which encoding your Workbench is using and make shure your PHP and your mysql-client are using the same. You will find this in the create script of the workbench and in the options of your client.

Also check on that script if there are actually double-quotes.

If that leads to nothing just change the values in the database to `&quot;` since you will use that table 99% for the frontend output and only 1% you are accessing via workbench.

Comment: You nailed the problem.  There was a mismatch in the encoding.  Their tables were using utf8_unicode_ui.  The tables I was loading the data into were latin1_general_ui.   I checked the table creation SQL they sent me and it was silent on encoding... so I'm guessing I have some default that assumes the later.

Thanks much!